# Listing members registered to a specific event

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 SQL tables

```
users (userId, name, secondname, ...)
events (eventId, eventName, eventDate, ...)
users_events (FK user (userId from users), FK event(eventId from events), datetimeRegistered)
```

Users can register to specific events listed, that's what the foreign keys are for.

I made a list of the events and when you click on one event, you get to a detailpage of that event where all the details are displayed and where you can register for the event. 
As soon as you register it INSERTS into the users_events with your userId and the eventId you clicked register on.

Now I would like to show a list in the detailpage of the members which registered already to this event.

#### Example:

"Bob" has userId "1".
"Fred" has userId "1".
The event they are registered to has eventId "2".

So the table users_events has 2 dates in it `eventId = 2, userId = 2` and `eventId = 2, userId = 2`

Now I want to list them in my detailpage.php like

```
Registered users: Bob, Fred
```

Comment: It is a simple inner join query. Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Never heard of it, never worked with it. Im quite new when it comes to sql and php. But thanks, atleast thats a hint which i can google now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeing you already know the event id you can construct an INNER JOIN like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.userId, u.name, u.secondname ....
FROM
    users_events ue
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON ue.userId = u.userId
WHERE
    ue.eventid = ???
```

replace the ??? with the event id you know.  Better yet parameterize the query when passing from your application.

Seeing as you say you are new and this is one of the more basic starting syntax questions I would recommend going through a SQL tutorial or two before trying to tackle too much and in place of asking a lot of questions because others are likely not to help you in the future if you don't make that effort.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i need, thank you very much buddy